# Case class vs regular class applied on RDD.map item

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need explanation of what is going on in the following Spark code:

```
case class SchemaItem(getName:String, getType:String);
val schemaItemList = sc.textFile("/spark/personsMetadata.txt").
                                flatMap(line=>line.split(",")).map(
                                        schemaItem=>SchemaItem(schemaItem.split("-")(0), schemaItem.split("-")(1))
                        ).collect().toList;
```

when I run this code in spark shell then I receive expected List of created SchemaItems objects.

When I change the SchemaItem case class to regular class then

1) I'm asked to make SchemaItem serialisable...Ok I extended SchemaItem from Serializable with @SerialVersionUID(15L) annotation to it.

2) schemaItemList after first point contains now not deserialised SchemaItems in the Driver program. Is it possible to receive deserialised Schemaitems?

Or does this mean that I should always use case classes in the workers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since Spark 1.6, Spark comes with support for automatically generating encoders for a wide variety of types, including primitive types (e.g. String, Integer, Long), Scala case classes, and Java Beans.

To save yourself from the trouble, the use of case classes is recommended.